# IndexOutOfBoundsException while trying to shuffle deck

Tags: java, random, shuffle

I am trying to shuffle a deck of cards.

```
public void shuffle()
{
    int rand1;
    int rand2;
    Random randomGenerator = new Random();

    for (int i = 0; i < deck.size(); i++) {

        // pick a random index between 0 and size of the deck - 1
        rand1 = randomGenerator.nextInt(10);
         rand2 = randomGenerator.nextInt(10);

        // swap rand1 and rand2
        Card temp = deck.get (rand1);
        deck.set(rand1, deck.get (rand2)); 
        deck.set(rand2, temp); 
    }
}
```

Then it says:

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException; Index:8; size:4(in java.util.ArrayList)
```

What's wrong?

Comment: Does `deck` have 10 cards? Why don't you do `randomGenerator.nextInt(deck.size());` instead?

Answer (score 6):

This line

```
rand1 = randomGenerator.nextInt(10);
```

should be

```
rand1 = randomGenerator.nextInt(deck.size());
```

and similarly for `rand2`.

Answer (score 3):

Another soultion (just if somebody needs to know)

create a list containing 1 to `deck.size()`. then shuffle it using [Collection.shuffle](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle%28java.util.List%29). Then the list will be shuffled with equal likelihood

Answer (score 2):

If this isn't for homework, use Collections.shuffle as @StinePike suggests.  If it is, you should know that you are not shuffling correctly. That is, not all results are equally likely. Here is a histogram produced by your algorithm (with @Jason 's correction) shuffling 3 numbers:

```
[1, 2, 3]: ***********************
[2, 3, 1]: ******************
[3, 2, 1]: **********************
[3, 1, 2]: ******************
[2, 1, 3]: **********************
[1, 3, 2]: **********************
```

And this is what is produced by a correct algorithm:

```
[1, 2, 3]: *********************
[2, 3, 1]: *********************
[3, 2, 1]: *********************
[3, 1, 2]: *********************
[2, 1, 3]: *********************
[1, 3, 2]: *********************
```

Collections.shuffle(deck) is correct, as is this:

```
public static <T> void shuffle(List<T> deck){
    int rand;
    for (int i = 0; i < deck.size()-1; i++) {
        // We randomly choose rand between i (inclusive) and deck.size()-1
        rand = i + randomGenerator.nextInt(deck.size()-i);

        // swap i and rand
        T temp = deck.get(rand);
        deck.set(rand, deck.get(i)); 
        deck.set(i, temp);
    }
}
```

Here's the code I used to produce the histograms. Note that the permutations don't always appear in the same order, but the same permutations ([2,3,1] and [3,1,2]) are consistently less likely.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Map<List<Integer>,Long> histogram = new HashMap<>();
    int logReps = 20;
    int scaleStar = logReps-7;
    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(1,2,3));
    for (int i = 0; i<(1<<logReps); i++) {
        List<Integer> templist = new ArrayList<Integer>(list);
        badShuffle(templist);
        if( histogram.containsKey(templist)) {
            histogram.put(templist,histogram.get(templist)+1L);
        } else {
            histogram.put(templist,1L);
        }
    }
    for(Entry<List<Integer>,Long> entry : histogram.entrySet()) {
        System.out.print(entry.getKey()+": ");
        for (int i=0; i<(entry.getValue()>>>scaleStar); i++) {
            System.out.print("*");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
static Random randomGenerator = new Random();
public static void badShuffle(List<Integer> deck){
    int rand1;
    int rand2;

    for (int i = 0; i < deck.size(); i++) {

        // pick a random index between 0 and size of the deck - 1
        rand1 = randomGenerator.nextInt(deck.size());
         rand2 = randomGenerator.nextInt(deck.size());

        // swap rand1 and rand2
        Integer temp = deck.get (rand1);
        deck.set(rand1, deck.get (rand2)); 
        deck.set(rand2, temp); 
    }
}
public static <T> void goodShuffle(List<T> deck){
    int rand;
    for (int i = 0; i < deck.size()-1; i++) {
        // We randomly choose rand between i (inclusive) and deck.size()-1
        rand = i + randomGenerator.nextInt(deck.size()-i);

        // swap i and rand
        T temp = deck.get(rand);
        deck.set(rand, deck.get(i)); 
        deck.set(i, temp);
    }
}
public static void libraryShuffle(List<Integer> deck){
    Collections.shuffle(deck);
}
```